# Getting values from php to ajax request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Greetings to everyone,

I'm a beginner in javaScript and I am kinda new to ajax... I am trying to get a return value from php like error message or success message and pass it to the user. Any kind of suggestion is welcome

PS: Everything was working when I have not started using ajax

```js
 $('button[post-request]').click(function() {
        // event.preventDefault();

        var request, address, form, response;
        address = $('form').attr('action');
        response = document.getElementById("return");

        $('input').prop('disabled', true);

        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', address, true);
        request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                response.innerHTML = this.responseText;

                console.log(request.responseText);

            }
            else{
                console.log(request.statusText);
            }
        }

        request.send();


    });
```

**Here is my php code**

```php
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{

    public $data, $uid;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // loading models
        $this->load->model(['logic/auth_action'=>'auth','validations/auth_validation'=>'verify']);

        // store ecncrypted user uid in a session
        $this->uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');

        $this->data['user'] = $this->usr->fetch_all_information($this->uid);
    }   

    public function login()
    {   
        $this->func->is_logged_in(true, 'dashboard');

        $this->data['title'] = "Sign in";

        if(!empty($_POST) && $this->input->is_ajax_request()):
            // validating users inputs coming from the form
            $user_inputs = $this->verify->authenticate_userInputs('login');

            // checking if no error isset && carry on with the next step
            if(!isset($user_inputs['error_msgs'])):
                // performing neccessary action after validating
                $return = $this->auth->login($user_inputs);
            else:
                // store error for $return variable if there is any && pass it on
                $return = $this->func->return_validation_error($user_inputs);
            endif;
            // retrieve the error stored and display it to user
            print $this->func->fetch_message('error',$return);
        endif;

        // this display login page
        $this->load->view('auth/login', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the `login` function in php?

Comment: N.B. since you're using jQuery, you might as well use jQuery's $.ajax function too, it's quite a bit easier to use than xmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Anyway I'd expect that `$this->load->view('auth/login', $this->data);` returns an entire HTML document. That doesn't make sense in the context of AJAX. You'd either want to return a HTML snippet which can be injected into the page already visible in the browser, or return some JSON data indicating the result of the request, which the receiving javascript can then use to decide what to do next, and what to display to the user (in that scenario the JS would be in charge of creating any necessary HTML and showing it). Does that help? It's a bit unclear precisely what you're stuck with.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, I called  it like this:- https;//localhost/site/auth/login

Comment: @ADyson, I don't feel like using jQuery and I am just think I should try something new

Comment: You're already using jQuery everywhere else in this code, though! And XmlHttpRequest isn't new, it's very legacy. If you don't want to use jQuery for AJAX, then the fetch API is the modern way to do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @ADyson, you absolute right, it's returning the entire html document for me but I don't really get what you are trying to say

Comment: `I don't really get what you are trying to say`...well returning an entire HTML document is no good because you can't insert that into the document which is already in the browser. You need the PHP to return either a) a small amount of HTML which can then be inserted somewhere within the existing document, or b) some data (e.g. in JSON format, which is pretty much the de-facto standard data interchange format on the web these days) which contains information about what the server has done (e.g. success or failure, any messages, and return values) which the receiving Javascript can use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229827/discussion-between-incredible-coder-and-adyson).